# Why is SmoothKernelDistribution not symmetric in 2D?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

For example, we create `SmoothKernelDistribution` from one data point in 2D, e.g. `{0,0}`. Why is the plot of `PDF` not symmetric around this point?

Observe where contour lines touch the image frame. Is this a bug, or is my understanding of `SmoothKernelDistribution` wrong?

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@PDF[
   SmoothKernelDistribution[{{0, 0}}],
   {x, y}
 ],
{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
PlotLegends -> Automatic,
Axes -> True
]
```

[image: contourPlot]

Comment: Clearly not the expected result, but is it a bug? It's probably a side effect of methods being used, error varies on basis of the bandwidth. What would you, by the way, expect the automatically calculated bandwidth to be for an input of a single point?

Comment: @kirma Regarding the automatically calculated bandwidth, I have no idea, I just posted the simplest example. But this effect is visible also with (different) prescribed values.

Comment: Interestingly setting `MaxRecursion` to *any* value, even `0`, will increase accuracy of `Mean` considerably. Results won't be exact with any value, though.

Comment: The following gets a more centered result:  `SmoothKernelDistribution[{{0, 0}}, Automatic, InterpolationPoints -> 500]`.

Comment: @JimB In theory, for one data point (e.g. `{0,0}`) results should be symmetric, right?

Comment: "In practice" no one would expect that `SmoothKernelDistribution` provide any answer other than "Don't talk to me until you have more data".  "In theory" what would you want/expect `SmoothKernelDistribution` to provide when there is no ability to estimate variances when there is just a single observation?  A bivariate kernel with infinite bandwidth centered on the data point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one should expect that giving `SmoothKernelDistribution` a single data point should provide any answer other than "Don't talk to me until you have more data" as there is no ability to estimate a bandwidth from the variation in the observations (as there is no variation).  However, I agree that if however a bandwidth is chosen, the resulting distribution should be centered on that data point.

Here is what I think happens.  `SmoothKernelDistribution` for a two-dimensional distribution is evaluated on a grid of 64 grid points (`InterpolationPoints`) in each direction by default.  However, you can set the number of `InterpolationPoints` to any positive number but that value gets bumped up to the next highest multiple of 2 (if what you give isn't a multiple of 2).

For either dimension the default grid points are as follows for a single observation:

```
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{0, 0}}];
skd[[2, 2, 1]]
(* {-3.17044, -3.06979, -2.96915, -2.8685, -2.76785, -2.6672, -2.56655, 
-2.4659, -2.36525, -2.2646, -2.16395, -2.0633, -1.96266, -1.86201, 
-1.76136, -1.66071, -1.56006, -1.45941, -1.35876, -1.25811, -1.15746, 
-1.05681, -0.956165, -0.855516, -0.754867, -0.654218, -0.553569, 
-0.45292, -0.352271, -0.251622, -0.150973, -0.0503245, 0.0503245, 
0.150973, 0.251622, 0.352271, 0.45292, 0.553569, 0.654218, 0.754867, 
0.855516, 0.956165, 1.05681, 1.15746, 1.25811, 1.35876, 1.45941, 
1.56006, 1.66071, 1.76136, 1.86201, 1.96266, 2.0633, 2.16395, 2.2646, 
2.36525, 2.4659, 2.56655, 2.6672, 2.76785, 2.8685, 2.96915, 3.06979, 
3.17044} *)
```

Consider the smallest absolute value which in this case is 0.0503245 and plot the point `{0.0503245, 0.0503245}` along with the contour plot:

```
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{0, 0}}];
xy = Min[Abs[skd[[2, 2, 1]]]];
Show[ContourPlot[Evaluate@PDF[skd, {x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Axes -> True],
 ListPlot[{{xy, xy}}]]
```

[image: Off-center contour plot]

Now lets try this with `InterpolationPoints -> 16`:

```
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[{{0, 0}}, InterpolationPoints -> 16];
xy = Min[Abs[skd[[2, 2, 1]]]];
Show[ContourPlot[Evaluate@PDF[skd, {x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Axes -> True],
 ListPlot[{{xy, xy}}]]
```

[image: Off center plot with fewer interpolation points]

With `InterpolationPoints -> 512` we get

[image: 512 InterpolationPoints]

(Strangely with `InterpolationPoints -> 8`, the contours are centered on `{-xy, -xy}`.)

I guess I wouldn't call this a bug but rather a feature whose effect can be minimized by choosing a large enough value of `InterpolationPoints`.